# Evernote PHP Cloud SDK Authorization Process

Tags: php, evernote

I have been unable to get Evernote PHP Cloud SDK to work.

I have production and sandbox accounts setup, a developer token for both, and an API KEY. Both accounts share the same email address, in case it matters.

I have the PHP Cloud SDK manually installed on hosted apache web server.

After some considerable debugging, I discovered that session values were not being stored during the ouath process. Hardcoding a session directory in the htaccess file took care of that problem, but I am still unable to connect the PHP to the evernote sandbox account.

I tried calling $client = new \Evernote\Client($token, $sandbox, null, null, $china); directly, with my developer key, but no dice.

I tried a zillion times connecting through oauth process, using supplied key and secret, but does not appear to return an oauth_token.

Sessions appear to be working, I have confirmed the files are being called correctly, and am seeing returns from the curl calls, except for the final handshake to retrieve the oauth_token.

There are two session calls in the supplied SDK oauth_handler file, and I do notice that a new session id is created on the second call, which may be a factor??

Any ideas on how to isolate the problem? Still not sure if it's a session, PHP configuration, "operator error", using wrong credentials to get into account, bugs in SDK, etc.

Assuming I can connect to my sandbox account, using the PHP Cloud SDK on a hosted web server, with developer token, following is small block of code that I cannot get to work:

```
<?php
require 'autoload.php';

$sandbox=true;
$china=false;
$token='...developer token...'; //developer token for sandbox account

// Set up the NoteStore client 
$client = new Client(array('token' => $token));
$noteStore = $client->getNoteStore();

// Make API calls
$notebooks = $noteStore->listNotebooks();
foreach ($notebooks as $notebook) {
print "Notebook: " . $notebook->name . "\n";
}
?>
```

I have also tried the block of code, going through the oauth process, without success.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to make sure you're starting a session in php, something like

`session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_start();`

See the php [session_start docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) for more information.